# Deactivate azure security policy for a specific resource

Tags: azure, azure-security

How can I deactivate an azure security policy for a specific resource? Policy shall be still applied to other resource in resource group / subscription.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Azure policy is assigned to a specific scope(**management group**, **subscription**, or **resource group**). I am afraid that there is no way to deactivate an Azure security policy for a specific resource.

However, you can exclude a subscope from the policy assignment.

If the scope is a group, you can just move that resource out of that group.

If the scope is subscription, you can exclude a resource group in that subscription that assigned different policy.

Answer (score 0):

All of my subscription with no resources have charges between 2-7CAD+ tax?
what is going on?
why even have different charges with no resources?
Microsoft assign me without asking me

Microsoft Defender for Cloud
Azure ARM service layers
35 subscriptions and the amounts are different two subscriptions with no resources and no usage got different amount.
I am 14 years with Azure, I was part of the private preview :-( sucks